# How to scale horizontally with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application where every user gets their own database. This lends itself to scale horizontally pretty well because it is easy to spin up another database server.

The part I am struggling with is how to identify the database server that a user's database/account is attached to.

Here are the possible solutions I have come up with:

1. Create a lookup table that maps username --> db server on one of the database servers. Make sure this query is indexed to negate any performance issues.

PROS: Easy to implement

CONS: Still have 1 point of failure. If the database server holding the username -->database relationship goes down, then the application stops working for all users

1. Create a text file that maps username --> database names

PROS: Pretty easy to implement and pretty fast.

CONS: Problems with keeping it in sync across web servers. Concurrency issues with writing to the file while being read. A small error in writing, could cause everything to go down

What is the best practice for something like this?

Comment: You can use option 1 on all database servers and do a master-master replication.

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep the first solution and export that regularly scheduled to the second option?

That way if everything goes down you have a means to get back up and get operational to your client base.

Comment: That sounds like a plan. Great idea, it combines both ideas.

Comment: Also, do you see any performance problems making a query that is indexed to lookup the database server for every request? I know I could cache it in memcached, but will the overhead be noticeable?

Comment: @ChrisMuench what is your table looking like?

Comment: @ChrisMuench I would cache the username/database mapping in memcache and I can assure you it wont be noticable. Good luck!